# repeated EJSONPARSE error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

"npm run react-dev" command gives this jsonparse error occurs repeatedly.

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token in JSON at position 595 while parsing ' { 
npm ERR!   "name": "reactnodetutorial",
npm ERR!   "vers'
```

Tried the following but none worked.

1) deleted all directories and files and restarted this project from the scratch like building architecture and installing dependencies

2) deleted all contents in package.json file and copied the tutorial example's package.json contents which is perfect and pasted it to mine

3) update node and npm to the latest version

4) npm init and reinstall dependencies

5) npm cache clean --force

6) rm -f package-lock.json

How to possibly fix this.

My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
"name": "reactnodetutorial",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "webpack.config.js",
"dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
  "express": "^4.16.3",
  "react": "^16.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
  "react-router": "^4.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "webpack": "^4.1.1"
  },
"devDependencies": {},
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
  "start": "node ./server/index.js",
  "build": "webpack -p",
  "react-dev": "webpack -d --watch",
  "server-dev": "nodemon server/index.js"
  },
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git+https://github.com/shinjehere/reactNodeTutorial.git"
  },
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"bugs": {
  "url": "https://github.com/shinjehere/reactNodeTutorial/issues"
  },
"homepage": "https://github.com/shinjehere/reactNodeTutorial#readme"
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire error that you have pasted here or is there something more - usually this kind of error comes when you are trying to parse some object that is not in JSON format especially when the object is an empty / undefined / null response or its not generated due to a failure. Is also provides the file location where this failure occurs.

Comment: try `rm package-lock.json` - https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3103

Comment: Delete the node_module folder and then try to do npm install

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I tried everything - delete node_module folder, rm package-lock.json - but nothing worked. At last, I just changed the package.json file to tutorial's package.json file and it worked.